# AngularJS revalidate on submit via directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm facing an issue which I can't seem to solve.
I have a field which I validate via a directive which matches the input value with a regex.

My input:

```
 <input type="text"
        name="emailaddress"
        class="form-control"
        ng-model="fields.emailaddress.value"
        ng-maxlength="fields.emailaddress.validation.maxLength"
        validator-emailaddress
        required />
```

My directive:

```
angular.module('forms')
    .directive('validatorEmailaddress', validatorEmailaddress);

/* @ngInject */
function validatorEmailaddress() {

    var directive = {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: link
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {

        var valid = false;

        var formatter = function (inputValue) {
            if (inputValue) {
                var res = inputValue.match(/^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/);
                if (res && res.length > 0) {
                    valid = true;
                }

                modelCtrl.$setValidity('pattern', valid);
                valid = false;
            } 
            return inputValue;
        };
        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(formatter);
        if (scope[attrs.ngModel] && scope[attrs.ngModel] !== '') {
            formatter(scope[attrs.ngModel]);
        }
    }
}
```

Now my issue is this:

**When I fill in the input, all is fine, however, when I fill the input with an invalid value, and then reopen the modal in this case, the invalid-pattern isn't present anymore, so the user can continue with an invalid input value.**

How can I make my directive check the input value also on submit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have defined a parser, not a validator, see Custom Validation (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

Comment: how you send the form.. directly via html? you can use ng-click() to call a function to validate your email and than send the form via angular $http.

Comment: I know its not what youre asking, but there is an ng-pattern attribute that you can add to an input field, it takes regex and if the input is incorrect it will give form.input.$error.pattern so you can use it for custom validation. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern

Comment: Ng-pattern is not what I am looking for. I made a directive so that I did not have to repeat the same code over and over for each field which require the same pattern. Thanks for your time though.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve same functionality using **ng-pattern**

Sample code -

```html
<div>
     <input type="text" ng-model="fields.email" name="email" ng-required="true" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.]{2,10}$/">
     <div ng-messages="formname.email.$error">
          <div ng-message="required" class="form-error"> *Email is required. </div>
          <div ng-message="pattern" class="form-error"> *Email address is invalid </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ng-pattern is not what I am looking for. I made a directive so that I did not have to repeat the same code over and over for each field which require the same pattern. Thanks for your time though.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by changing my directive a bit. I'll post my directive for future reference:

```
angular.module('forms')
    .directive('validatorEmailaddress', validatorEmailaddress);

/* @ngInject */
function validatorEmailaddress() {

    var directive = {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: link
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {

        var valid = false;

        var formatter = function (inputValue) {
            if (inputValue) {
                var res = inputValue.match(/^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/);
                if (res && res.length > 0) {
                    valid = true;
                }

                modelCtrl.$setValidity('pattern', valid);
                valid = false;
            } 
            return inputValue;
        };
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (inputValue) { // This did the trick
            formatter(inputValue);
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks to Fantarama who pointed me in the right direction. Instead of using a parser I use a validator now.